# Cycles Render Engine on but still no Surface Option

Tags: cycles-render-engine, world

I am having a problem. I am following a tutorial for a Minecraft animation in blender but the person wanted to change the sky color so he used the surface tab to do so once background was enabled.

I enabled mine but no surface option to change the background.

I looked around saw that you needed cycles render on but I already had it enabled.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will find the surface option in the "world" tab.

[image: Surface option in world tab]